# Mouse takes a few seconds to respond

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I'm not terribly sure what to make of this. I use the following mouse
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-mouse-m185.
If I don't touch the mouse for a few seconds, it doesn't move immediately (say within a second) move moving the actual mouse. In other words, expected response is, move mouse, see cursor move across the screen. Actual response, move mouse, wait about 2 seconds and suddenly the mouse moves. After the initial move, it moves just fine again (even with letting it set for a bit). But if I leave it for a couple minutes and come back, I have the same issue. I have also tried replacing the battery in it, thinking maybe its just dead and Ubuntu didn't notice it.

Its almost like I have to "wake it up" with a movement. Its driving me nuts. I've tried different mice and am getting the same issue. Tried different DE's (Desktop Environments) and the issue persists. I cannot figure this out, though I'm thinking it has something to do with power management?

This has started happening "relatively" recently, I'd say in the past month or so.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue to me.  Have you tried the mouse with a different OS?

Comment: I've used the mouse on my surface 3 with no issues at all.

Comment: Not hardware then...  Sorry, but I don't have any more suggestions.

Comment: @miversen33 may I ask if you could resolve this? If you did, how?

Comment: @DeeStarks I don't actually remember and I no longer use that mouse. If I had to go back in time and guess, this smells like a kernel issue related to the wireless driver. At this point though, this is 6 years old, I don't really remember unfortunately. I know that isn't helpful. Sorry :/